# $.getScript() and $(window).load() in Safari 5 not always working

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, load

I'm experiencing a similar problem to [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526315/strange-jquery-window-load-behavior-in-safari) except my problem is related to scripts and not images.

I'm using a combination of `$.getScript()` and `$(window).load()` to load JavaScript dynamically and use functions that are being loaded once the script has completely finished loading.

It works well in Chrome but Safari seems to always fire the `onload` event too early. I was wondering if there was some way to force Safari to wait for all scripts to load similarly to the `document.body.offsetWidth` block. From what I understood (and from the results I saw when I tested it), `document.body.offsetWidth` blocks until styles and images are loaded but apparently not scripts.

Edit: It might be worth mentioning that it *does* work in Safari sometimes but I don't see a pattern. Sometimes the event is fired before the script is fully loaded and executed and the handler passed `$(window).load()` fails because the functions are missing.

Comment: why can't you use the `success` handler for `$.getScript()`? This will run once the script has finished loading.

Comment: i think the real question here is why are you dynamically loading required scripts.

Comment: @Kevin Peno: I need the rest of the scripts to load as well, not just one script. There are several scripts being loaded. They're all separated into their own script depending on their functionality.

Comment: @nathan gonzalez: It's for work (and I'm an intern) and I'm required to do it this way, otherwise I wouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments you have made, specifically those surrounding dependencies, I would use a library like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). This will give you what you need to import scripts and their dependencies, and also hooks to call functions and code when dependencies are met.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at Namespace.js at some point also. I'll take a look at this one too and evaluate it with co-workers. I'll get back to you when I can.

Comment: This will most likely work but I don't think I'd be able to get this approved at work. I'll still mark it as right since it's the best solution I've come across so far. I should also mention [LABjs](http://labjs.com/) as well since it looks like another decent solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the good old document ready?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  //code here 
})
```

I've never had any issues when using that. Worst case scenario, you can drop a script tag after all your other script tags that include the code you require.

Comment: That won't help, I don't think, as the problem is that the "ready" mechanism doesn't know to wait for dynamically loaded scripts.

Comment: This won't work because `$(document).ready()` binds a handler to the DOMContentLoaded event which fires after the DOM is ready but before the scripts/images/css is ready. Like I said, my code works in Chrome without fail every time.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I tell loaded scripts that I need to do something to report loaded to a function. Once all that I need are loaded, I run whatever code I need to.

```
// Simplified callback to check for all scrips loaded.
var numDynScriptsReady = 0,
    numDynScriptsNeeded = 4;

function dynScriptsReady()
{
    numDynScriptsReady++;

    if( numDynScriptsLoaded == numDynScriptsNeeded )
    {
        // Run functions you need after loaded....
    }
}

// Example script get
$.getScript( "http://example.com/script.js", dynScriptsReady );
// etc....
```

Comment: This is interesting but this means I would have to count the number of scripts every time I write a handler/add another import. The main issue is that I'll have one script that does something very specific and that script will, in turn, import its own dependencies within itself. So there are imports within the imported scripts and that complicates things when needing to count them.

Comment: @alexcoco, So expand on it then. You can use `$.data` to store the dependency count for the particular `script`, similar to the global `var`. You can use the function as a `$.bind` on newly added script elements, then `$.trigger` for the `success` callback of that particular `$.getScript`. As an intern, I'd expect it to be fun for you to figure it out!

Comment: Storing the value isn't so much the issue. The issue is knowing how many scripts need to be imported. If I have to count them every time then I might as well store everything in one big file.

Comment: @alex, the only way to know that each script has loaded and that each of its dependencies has loaded would be to "know" that it has somehow. Thus you need something simple like this or something larger...see my other answer.

Comment: I understand what you mean but it does work in Chrome as is so it seems to be some sort of issue with Safari not working as expected. Safari is the only browser so far that it seems to fail in. Thanks for the other answer, I'll take a look at it.